# Algorithm of order $O(n)$

Tags: algorithms

Design an $O(n)$ algorithm, that given a real number $x$ and a sorted array $S$ of $n$ numbers, determine whether there exists any two elements in $S$ whose sum is exactly $x$.

The solution I have designed is that first taking a loop of order $n$, it traverses the array $S$ to find the number closest to $x$ but less than $x$, say $S[y]$. Then again taking another loop outside of this loop i again traverse the array from the first to $y-1$ and check by adding the data accessed by the loop with the $S[y]$ and check the sum with $x$. Am I correct? Is there a case for which this algorithm fails?

Comment: take $x = 11$ ans $S = [2,3,8,10]$, your algorithm fails to find $3+8=11$

Comment: ok, i i must have a specific condition if the closest element is at the end of the list or not, thanks a lot!

Comment: even it's not at the end, take $S = [2,3,8,10,12]$ for example, it doesn't work

Comment: ok, cant come up with anything

Comment: Make a new (sorted) array of differences $x-S[i]$. Is searching two sorted arrays for common elements  $O(n)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**. Start with $a := 1$ and $b := n$. Now look at $s := S[a] + S[b]$, if $s > x$, decrease $b$ by $1$, if $s < x$, increase $a$ by $1$. You either find a pair or end up with $b < a$, in which case there is no such pair.

Answer (score 1):

1. Let $i=1$, $j=n$.
2. If $i>j$, terminate: No solution exists. (If the elements are required to be distinct, test for $i\ge j$ instead).
3. If $a_i+a_j=x$, terminate: Solution found
4. If $a_i+a_j<x$, let $i\leftarrow i+1$ and go back to 2.
5. Let $j\leftarrow j-1$ and go back to 2.

Each time step 2 is reached, the differenec $j-i$ decreases by one, starting with $n-1$. Hence the loop repeats only $O(n)$ times.